# Regex - Get strings in Quotes ignore escaped Quotes and Comments

Tags: c#, regex, string, escaping, quotes

I need help with my regex. I use C#.
I need an regex with matches all strings which are within quotes, but i need to ignore the escaped quotes in the string and the strings which are in comment like this.

// "Hello Guys" -> Ignore string

SayHello("**Hello i \"need\" our help**"); -> match whole string.

The regex i current use is this: [Demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/hN0jG4/18)

Comment: I would do it in more steps. I think it could be very hard to do it using one only regex

Comment: I will probably not get around. But i am confused about this regex: //.*|/\\*(?>[^*]+|\\*(?!/))*\\*/|(\"(?:\\\"|[^\"])*\") This regex works fine at debuggex.com but when i use this one in csharp i get strange matches.

Comment: In you match example, when you say _"match whole string"_, you mean the `SayHello` function too or just `Hello i \"need\" our help`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use negative lookbehind if you know exacly the length of character before comment with string. Because negative lookbehind cant use quantifier. Something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/RBLANz/1) :

```
(?<!\/\/.)".*?[^\\]"
```

Or do this. Remove all comment that use `//` with this regex

```
\/\/.*
```

then use this to get all strings

```
".*?[^\\]"
```

Comment: Thanks thats what i need :) Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Ecluding stuff (dealing with complements) is not what regular expressions are good for (not counting some [more or less exotic extensions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions/), but the regular expressions in the spirit of automata theory and formal languages).

The // comments would need to get filtered out or replaced by harmless content in its own pass.

The \" escapes would need a similar treatment.

Then you could match the defused content with some regular expression.